# Complex C++ Text File IO

Tags: c++, parsing, fstream

I want to create a reusable program that creates a random multiple choice test out of a text file. The text file would hold the question, answer, and other incorrect answers. I want the program to search for keywords that identify parts of the text file. Here is how the text file is now (The example is for a bone anatomy test):

```
Q0 "What bone is the supraorbital foramen found on?" [Frontal Bone]
Q1 "What bone is the Sella Turcica found on?" [Sphenoid Bone]
Q2 "What bone is the Crista Galli found on?" [Cribriform Plate]
Q3 "What bone is the Foramen Magnum found on?" [Occipital Bone]
Q4 "What bone is next to the Ulna?" [Radius]

W0 <Frontal Bone>
W1 <Sella Turcica>
W2 <Carpals>
W3 <Temporal Bone>
W4 <Femur>
W5 <Ulna>
W6 <Sphenoid Bone>
W7 <Crista Galli>
W8 <Cribriform Plate>
W9 <Mandible>
W10 <Radius>
W11 <Foramen Magnum>
W12 <Occipital Bone>
W13 <Leg>
W14 <Arm>
```

Q0 means question 0. What is next to it in quotes is the question, the answer is in brackets. W0 and on is the word bank, which is other potential answers. I think what I need is called a parser. I am still a beginner, sort of. I just need to know how to get the program to read this file and display it correctly. I'm not asking for the program to be written for me, I just want some advice for making a parser with this format.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly take care of data structures - it's a good practice. As you see, there are may be these structures:

```cpp
map<string, int> answers;

struct question {
    int id;
    string text;
    int answer;
}

list<question> questions;
```

As you see it's better to place answers in file before questions. Why? Because you can write a program by this way:

1. Parse answers and fill `answers` map.
2. Parse question and fill `questions`. Just put an answer's number in `answers[answer_string]` to get a corresponding answer's number.

Now you have everything to create an algorithm.
Lets see how does generally work a simple parser for this case:

1. Skip all spaces.
2. Read a symbol `s`. If `s == 'W'` then read an answer's number. Else if `s == 'Q'` read a question's number.
3. If `s == '"'` read a question's string until next '"'.
4. If `s == '['` read a question's answer string until ']'.
5. If `s == '<'` read an answer's string until '>'.

Just use these rules and you will get a recursive parsing algorithm. Also it would be good to read about [recursive descent parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) for details.

That's all! You have data structures and an algorithm. Now you can write some code.

And why not to use a number for question's answer instead of string to reduce duplications? :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use a XML format instead of a text file. There are several free XML parsers already out on the market so you would not need to write much parsing code.

Another benefit is that if you later decide to change the format it is easier then rewriting the parser.

The third benefit is that you get your questions and answers built up in a hierarchy which suits very well to be held in data structures.